Is d > n for all d > 2 , where n is the number of digits in the binary representation of d?
Is d > n for all d > 2, where n is the number of digits in the binary representation of d?
Let d be a positive integer represented in the decimal system, and let n be the number of digits in the binary representation of d.
Is it true that d > n for all d > 2?
I have an intuitive understanding of why this might hold, by testing it out on smaller numbers, however can someone please help me with a way to prove this more rigorously?
For reference, I am a high school math student, so I would really appreciate an explanation geared towards my level of understanding.
TIA

This amounts to saying the smallest number with $n$ binary digits, $2^{n-1}$, exceeds $n$. Can you prove this for $n\ge3$ with mathematical induction?

Let $d$ be a number, and $\varepsilon_{n}\ldots\varepsilon_0$ be its binary representation. Notice that $n$ is the largest power of $2$ such that $2^n\leq d$. Therefore $d\geq 2^n>n+1$ for all $n\geq 2$.
To see the last inequality, we can prove it by induction. For $n=2$ the statement is clear. Assume $2^n>n+1$. Then:
$$2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n>2(n+1)=2n+2>n+2$$
